# How to run 3rd party application from my CLI application written in Golang?

Tags: go

I am newbie in Golang but thanks to my C-language knowledge. I could do some feature development on existing legacy code base.
I have a CLI based application written in Go. We are interacting with this app also with custom made command like :

```
./my_app -s /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 init ( opens application via Serial Interface)
```

My question is, I have a 3rd party application, that am giving some .txt input. This app doing some conversion and outputs a file.

I want to attach this application's executable to my application and interact with that application over my own application with the help of a new command like

`./my_app -s /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 convert "./my_file.txt" "output path file to be generate"`

I need similar topic may give me a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

The [go/exec](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec) package handles the execution of external commands. To execute your given command you could write code like this:

```go
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("./my_third_party_executable", "-s", "/dev/ttyACM0", "-b", "115200", "convert" "./my_file.txt", "output path file to be generate")
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure your approach is true.

1. This command should enter from command line. This my case and I can handle.

2. Command should call .exe of 3rd part program over my_app backend and arguments that I passed should also passed to the executable with same way if possible.

3. If possible, end-user should not see 3rd party UI when we call, we may inform over Error returns.

Comment: I would accept this answer as correct, but I would also urge you to use other means (existing go bindings for an application, some networked API) if at all possible.  Exec is always a last resort, and imposes external dependencies on users.  But yes, this is how you would do it.

Comment: If I'm understanding the example correctly, your Command probably should look more like this: `exec.Command("convert" "./my_file.txt", "output path file to be generate")`

Comment: If  example is correct, where is the point .exe is called ? On the other hand, we wish to give our customer just our my_app executable. Now it seems, this way is not feasible. Somehow, I have to add this 3rd party app into my_app during building process. Does it make sense to you ?

Comment: Oh I think, I got it. in the example

it should be like that:

 cmd := exec.Command("the path of third party.exe", "-s", "/dev/ttyACM0", "-b", "115200", "convert" "./my_file.txt", "output path file to be generate")